# How to Add Telegraf Command Parameters?

Tags: node.js, telegraf.js

hello I am writing a telegram bot but I want to add parameters to my commands, for example /command -gsm 921

how do i do the same with telegraf node.js i write my bot

I would appreciate your help :))

and I want to specify this parameter, for example, I want it to detect the number I write and send something accordingly, I will be glad if you send me an example.